# Apple TV as an external UIScreen on an iOS device

Tags: c#, ios, apple-tv, uiscreen, external-display

I have an app that displays video in a subview and where it would be nice to give the option to display that video on a second screen such as an Apple TV and be able to use that freed-up space to show additional controls.

I've found all sorts of help about how to do that, but I'm hitting a wall even before getting out of the starting gate.

In order to detect that the app has started up in a multiple display environment, all the sample code features a line like...

```
if (UIScreen.Screens.Length > 1) {
    // ...
}
```

(I'm doing this in C#/Xamarin, though I doubt the problem is related to that; anyway, the snippets are in C#)

My problem is that the array of screens is always 1 no matter what I do. The iPad is running iOS 11.2.5, and if I turn on mirroring, the iPad is mirrored, but , again, the array of screens only has a single item.

There are also a couple of observers to detect screens being added/removed while the app is running. I haven't seen Xamarin specific code, but I presume it looks like:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this, UIScreen.DidConnectNotification, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, IntPtr.Zero);
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this, UIScreen.DidDisconnectNotification, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Anyway, those never fire even if I add/remove the Apple TV or enter/exit Mirroring Mode on the iPad.

Oh; also if I do

```
avPlayer.AllowsExternalPlayback = true;
avPlayer.UsesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = true;
```

then that works as expected, too. The video now appears full-screen on the Apple TV and the UIView on the iPad containing the avPlayer greys out rather than showing the video.

However, that's not what I'm looking for. I would like to control the layout of both screens and that does neither. (While I do want the video to be full screen on the Apple TV, I don't want it to be an AVPlayerViewController and I do want to repurpose the screen real-estate taken up by the iPad video view)

At the end of the day, all I think I need is to manage to get

UIScreen.Screens.Length to be equal to 2 when I launch the app.

What's the secret of getting UIScreen to detect/report a second display?

Comment: AirPlay appears to be deprecated [developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1624258-allowsairplayvideo) in favour of External Displays. More practically, on my iPad (running iOS 11), mirroring is the only option available in the control center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an app is launched with screen mirroring already enabled, the `UIScreen.screens` array initially only contains the device's screen.  Shortly after launch, iOS posts a `UIScreenDidConnect` notification to advise your app that a second screen is connected.

What you will see at launch is that the `captured` property of your main screen is `true` if mirroring is enabled, however you can't actually access the second screen until after the notification is posted. Note that `captured` could also indicate that screen recording is in progress.

Although this seems slightly counter-intuitive it actually makes your coding a little simpler; you need to observe the `UIScreenDidConnect` and `UIScreenDidDisconnect` notifications *anyway* and now you don't need to write any special code to handle the case where the app is launched with a second screen already attached.

You can use something like this in your `didFinishLaunching`:

```
let nc = NotificationCenter.default

nc.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenDidConnect, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
    print("Screen connected")
    self.enableExternalDisplay()
}

nc.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIScreenDidDisconnect, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
    print("Screen disconnected")
    self.disableExternalDisplay()
}
```

**UPDATE**

Actually, it looks like you have the key/value observing format of `AddObserver` in your code, when you actually want notification observing.  Something like:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIScreen.DidConnectNotification,OnScreenConnected)
```

And then you need to implement an `OnScreenConnected` method.

Comment: No apologies necessary for the Swift code. The insight that UIScreens only have one item at launch being an expected thing is useful; it alows me to focus on why I'm not seeing the notification. Since NSNotification.Name.UIScreenDidConnect is presumably a const, could you post what the underlying string is? The C# and Swift code otherwise appears identical so the string I'm passing in seems to be a candidate for what the underlying problem might be.

Comment: It is "UIScreenDidConnectNotification", although in Swift you use `NSNotification.Name` enumeration values.  That string is the raw value of the enumeration.

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong format for `AddObserver` - the format you are using is for key/value observing.  You want [this format](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNotificationCenter/)